# PKCS1 and blind RSA signatures

Tags: rsa, blind-signature

Wikipedia's article on [RSA blind signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature#Blind_RSA_signatures.5B2.5D:235) says that you need to raise the message $m$ to the secret exponent $d$ modulo the public modulus $N$.

Implicit within that, it seems to me, is that m needs to be less than $N$. Problem with that is that that's not a restriction imposed upon signatures.

So for blind signatures to work as Wikipedia describes them you need to set $m$ to the hash or to the output of `EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5-ENCODE` or `EMSA-PSS-ENCODE` instead of setting $m$ to the plaintext. And then you do the modular exponentiation after you've blinded $m$.

IE.: you kinda have to side-step `RSASSA-PSS-SIGN` or `RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN` for blind signatures to work correctly.

Is that correct?

Comment: Related questions: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5626/6961 and http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2364/6961

Comment: I'd certainly choose a deterministic padding for blind signatures. In the simplest case, full domain hash.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not correct.  You appear to have a misconception about how RSA signatures work.

Here is how an RSA signature is generated:

- You take your message $M$
- You apply a padding function to create a value $m = pad(M)$
- You then use the RSA private key to compute $m^d \bmod N$

Now, this last step isn't always done in the straight-forward manner.  With blinded RSA signatures, it's done using a random value $r$ to defeat some side channel attacks; however that isn't that important for how RSA signatures work in general.  In particular, the value that a blinded RSA computes is precisely the same as a nonblinded version; it just uses a different algorithm to get that value.  In addition, that's the only part that's different for "blinded RSA signatures"; in all other respects, they are computed precisely like any other RSA signature.

You appear to be expecting that you can skip step 2, and step the value $m$ to the message $M$.  However, that can be dangerous; one of the issues with using  RSA without padding is that the RSA operation (either public or private) preserves multiplication, that is:

$RSA(a) \times RSA(b) = RSA( a \times b )$

(where both multiplications is done modulo $N$).

What this means is that if someone gets a series of messages $m_1, m_2, ..., m_n$ with their unpadded signatures $RSA(m_1), RSA(m_2), .., RSA(m_n)$, they may be able to find a message $m_{evil} = m_1^{e_1} m_2^{e_2} ... m_n^{e_n}$ (for some set of exponents $e_1, e_2, ..., e_n$; note that some exponents may be negative).  The attacker typically can do this if some of the $m_1, m_2, ..., m_n$ values are smooth (consists of only small factors); if there are enough smooth values, the attacker may be able to find a subset that they can recombine to form $m_{evil}$.  If that attacker can do that, that means that he can immediately deduce the signature $RSA( m_{evil}) = RSA(m_1)^{e_1} RSA(m_2)^{e_2} ... RSA(m_n)^{e_n}$

Signature padding methods are designed to prevent this; the value $pad(M)$ are large values, and hence are extremely unlikely to be smooth.

Hence, it is considered a Good Idea to always have a padding method when generating RSA signatures.

Comment: I'm not proposing unpadded rsa. I'm proposing doing EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5-ENCODE but not the full blown RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN

Comment: @neubert: Huh?  The EMSA-PKCS1-V1_5-ENCODE is just the padding operation.  Are you saying that you'll be doing the padding, but not the RSA part?  If not, what are you saying?

Comment: You do EMSA-PKCS1-V1_5-ENCODE, blind and then do modular exponentiation. RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN is EMSA-PKCS1-V1_5-ENCODE and modular exponentiation. Blinding has to be done in the middle of those two, it seems to me, hence my saying you have to side-step RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that it necessarily needs to be broken up anyway. If you were going to sign the message wouldn't be a blind signature. It'd be a regular signature. So you pad the message, don't do RSA, blind it, and then send it off to the signer for them to sign it. But since they're signing a blinded message they wouldn't know what the original message was. Of course since you're sending a padded hash it seems to me that they wouldn't know what the orig message was anyway. Unless I'm totally misunderstanding blind signing.

Comment: @neubert When you actually use blind signatures (e.g. to implement Chaumian E-Cash) then the padding is done by a different entity than the private key operation. One important consequence is that the padder wants to forge signatures, so it doesn't seem like a good idea to use a probabilistic padding scheme.

Comment: @neubert With blind signatures the *blinder/padder* pads and then blinds the message. The *signer* operates on the blinded signature. The *blinder* then unblinds the signature, giving them a properly padded signature that isn't blinded anymore. The verifier works with the unblinded signature and knows the signed message. So they can verify normal padding with hashes etc.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - that jibes with my understanding. Although I'm not sure why a probabilistic padding scheme would be bad? I'm also unsure of why, when you already have a hash, blinding is necessary, since the hash pretty much obscures the message already. I guess I'll start a new question for that lol